# Drink from the can?

Tags: taste

Why is The Alchemist Heady Topper recommended to "Drink from the can"? Also, are there other beers that "should" also be drank from the can?

Comment: Some general insight here, perhaps? http://www.businessinsider.com.au/why-canned-beer-is-better-2013-8

Comment: I would say no.  Wayne's linked to the video that explains why the founder of The Alchemist thinks you should drink his beer from a can and he knows best how he wants his beer to be experienced, but for me, the scent and flavor restrictions are too much.  Don't get me wrong, I certainly enjoy drinking beer from a can, (and I'm drinking one from a bottle right now) but it's just better in a proper glass.

Comment: I agree, I can see his reasoning but a part of taste is also sight and smell. Placing the beer in a proper glass enhances both of these which in turn leads to a better overall experience. Just my opinion

Answer (score 4):

Here is what the founder has to say:
http://www.beerpulse.com/2013/04/why-to-drink-alchemist-heady-topper-out-of-the-can-and-other-questions-answered-video/

Sounds like oxidation is a main reason, but he gives several other reasons.

Comment: Perhaps you could quote a relevant line or two inline with your answer so we don't have to go off-site to get the gist of the thing.

Comment: "Sounds like oxidation is a main reason"

Comment: sounds like from the can tastes amazing!